# Windows Phone 8 Panaroma Application Tile Title

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, title, tile

I am trying to write on panaroma application in tile image title.
And I can not see like a below code in .xaml page;

```
<image Title="blabla" ...>
```

This is my code;

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="Kişisel Bilgiler" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!--Double wide Panorama with large image placeholders-->
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,4,16,0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,12,0,0">
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel>

                            <Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="1" Margin="12,0,0,0">

                               <Image Width="173" Height="173" Source=".\Assets\cinsiyet.png" Tag="img_deneme" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="img_cins" MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" />

                            </Border>
                        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                 </StackPanel>
             </Grid>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

[image: Output is here]

But I want to [image: like this]

Thank is advance.
(Sorry my language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` control doesn't have any property to display text similar to `Tile`'s title. You need to add other control to display the title, for example using `TextBlock` :

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="1" Margin="12,0,0,0">
           <Image Width="173" Height="173" Source=".\Assets\cinsiyet.png" Tag="img_deneme" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="img_cins" MouseEnter="Image_MouseEnter" />
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,150,0,0" Text="Tile Title" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
</toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

You may also want to try [HubTile](http://igrali.com/2011/08/19/how-to-use-the-hubtile-control/) control as an alternative.

Comment: It is very illustrative examples. Thanks for everything har07.